# CRFClassifier: loading model from a stream gives exception "invalid stream header: 1F8B0800"

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to load a `CRFClassifier` model from a file. This way works:

```
// this works
classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier("../res/stanford-ner-2018-02-27/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");
```

**When I want to use stream**, however, I get `invalid stream header: 1F8B0800` exception:

```
// this throws an exception
String modelResourcePath = "../res/stanford-ner-2018-02-27/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(modelResourcePath));
classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(stream);
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 1F8B0800
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:866)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1473)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1456)
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.getClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2890)
at com.sv.research.ner.stanford.StanfordEntityExtractor.<init>(StanfordEntityExtractor.java:34)
at com.sv.research.ner.stanford.StanfordEntityExtractor.main(StanfordEntityExtractor.java:59)
```

I would expect both ways to be equivalent. My reason to load through a stream is that ultimately I want to load the model from JAR resources using:

```
stream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(modelResourcePath));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the classifier you are trying to use was serialized via GZIPInputStream as far as I could see from their sources.

So can you try deserializing the way that they serialize, like this:

```
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(modelResourcePath)));
```

Cheers

Comment: Worked like a charm, accepted. I am curious, does it make more sense to put BufferedInputStream before or after GZIPInputStream?